# stripe api onClick suscribe buttons not bringing up the api screen

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

The code produces a Netflix clone subscription page, and upon pushing the subscribe button.

It's supposed to go to a screen held on Stripe, can anyone see why this is not the case. Nothing happens when I click the subscribe button.

It's supposed to go to a payments page that was designed, edited and held in Stripe.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {selectUser} from "./features/userSlice";
import db from "./firebase";
import "./PlanScreen.css";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";


const PlanScreen = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("products")
      .where("active", "==", true)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        const products = {};
        querySnapshot.forEach(async (productDoc) => {
          products[productDoc.id] = productDoc.data();
          const priceSnap = await productDoc.ref.collection("prices").get();
          priceSnap.docs.forEach((price) => {
            products[productDoc.id].prices = {
              priceId: price.id,
              priceData: price.data(),
            };
          });
        });

        setProducts(products);
      });
  }, []);
  console.log(products);

//loadCheckout functionality - loadCheckout session in stripe

  const loadCheckout = async (priceId) => {
     const docRef = await db
     .collection('custoemrs')
     .doc(user.uid)
     .collection("checkout_sessions") 
     .add({
         price: priceId,
         success_url: window.location.origin,
         cancel_url: window.location.origin,
//helps us return to the screen we were on
     });
        
        docRef.onSnapshot(async(snap)=> {
          const {error, sessionId } = snap.data();

          if (error) {
            //show an error to your customer and
            //inspect your Cloud Function logs in the Firebase console
            alert(`An error-occured: ${error.message}`);
          }
            if (sessionId) {
              // we have a sesson, ket's redirect to Checkout 
              // Init Stripe

            const stripe =  await loadStripe("pk_test_123");
             stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId});
            }
        });
     //Redirects user towards the checkout page 
  };

  //fetch plans from the database + load them up on screen

  return (
    <div className="planScreen">
      {Object.entries(products).map(([productId, productData]) => {
        
        // TODO: add some logic to check if useers subsciption is active
        return (
          <div className="planScreen_plan">
            <div className="planScreen_info">
              <h5>{productData.name}</h5>
              <h6>{productData.description}</h6>
            </div>
            <button onClick={()=> loadCheckout(productData.prices.priceId)}>Suscribe</button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      {/*passes an array back to us after mapping through object*/}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PlanScreen;
```

Comment: What sort of errors are you encountering? What do you expect to happen? I don't see you creating a checkout session. What happens during that `.add()` call? Do you get back an expected `sessionId`?

Comment: I don't get the sessionId. The site is co-hosted using Firebase and Stripe the page is part of a react component that presents me with the option to subscribe to different plans, however nothing happens when I click on any of the subscribe buttons, it's supposed to bring up a page hosted on a stripe website . I just want to check the code is ok at this end.